# Duplicate invocation on display number: 0

Tags: windows-10, ssh, xming, xforwarding

I am trying to connect X11 forwarding from my local, Windows 10 box to a remote CentOS 7 server. Putty (with X11 enabled) works fine; I have command line access at the local server. I have Xming installed as the local X server.

On my local box, I see the Xming icon in the task icon tray. Clicking on it, I can "View Log." Here is what the log looks like.

```
Welcome to the Xming X Server
Vendor: Colin Harrison
Release: 6.9.0.31
FreeType2: 2.3.4
Contact: http://sourceforge.net/forum/?group_id=156984

Xming :0 -multiwindow -clipboard 

XdmcpRegisterConnection: newAddress 10.32.203.137
winCheckDisplayNumber - Xming is already running on display 0

Fatal server error:
InitOutput - Duplicate invocation on display number: 0.  Exiting.

winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
```

I found this while troubleshooting X11 forwarding that isn't working. Evidently, starting the server with the :0 display option is invalid.

Why is :0 not working? What should I use when I start Xming? I start from XLauncher.exe; how do I fix this problem when starting there (and not on the command line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be safely ignored. The following portion of the log message indicates that Xming is already running on display 0. A duplicate instance of Xming cannot be run on the same display, so duplicate instance is shut down.

```
winCheckDisplayNumber - Xming is already running on display 0

Fatal server error:
InitOutput - Duplicate invocation on display number: 0.  Exiting.

winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
```

This error is not the cause of your X11 forwarding issue. I get the exact same log message on Ubuntu Windows Subsystem for Linux but it does not interfere with X11 forwarding. Trying to start Xming from XLauncher or the command line will yield the same results if Xming is already running.